# Adding a type of heading to a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hey all, im not sure if this is possible but i am looking to add a heading to a query's output. The best way to describe this is just by showing what i would like the output to look like:

```
[heading here]
<skip row>
[Another Header here]
MemebersID | FirstName | LastName | Email              | OrderDate
05466        Bob         Barker     Bob@aol.com          2010-05-11
05946        Jan         Lowers     JLo@aol.com          2010-09-11
06456        Tony        Montana    TonyM@aol.com        2010-01-11
```

So here's what it would look like with the headers in place:

```
Top Users Records

The Memebers
MemebersID | FirstName | LastName | Email              | OrderDate
05466        Bob         Barker     Bob@aol.com          2010-05-11
05946        Jan         Lowers     JLo@aol.com          2010-09-11
06456        Tony        Montana    TonyM@aol.com        2010-01-11
```

Is that possible as the output of a query using MS SQL 2005?

**@KM**

Because the report looks like that when all said and done....

```
Top Users Records

The Memebers
MemebersID | FirstName | LastName | Email              | OrderDate
05466        Bob         Barker     Bob@aol.com          2010-05-11
05946        Jan         Lowers     JLo@aol.com          2010-09-11
06456        Tony        Montana    TonyM@aol.com        2010-01-11

The Users
MemebersID | FirstName | LastName | Email              | OrderDate    | Bill
05466        Bob         Barker     Bob@aol.com          2010-05-11     $5.66
05946        Jan         Lowers     JLo@aol.com          2010-09-11     $95.05
06456        Tony        Montana    TonyM@aol.com        2010-01-11     $9.02
```

Any help would be great! Thanks :)

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to do this in SSRS?

Comment: SSRS is free with SQL Server, supported to Express Edition (dunno about Compact).

Answer (score 2):

Adding formatting headings to the query is really an application issue, with not much you can do in TSQL, this is about the best you can do:

```
PRINT '[heading here]'
PRINT ' '
PRINT '[Another Header here]'
SELECT ....
```

Comment: Needs to be within the query itself

Comment: @StealthRT, why does it need to be in the query itself?